# Sqoop import query where ID between row_numbers does not work

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop

Other questions have been asked/answered but none could point towards answering my question below:

I am importing just a limited range of rows (e.g., "where _ID between 107 and 307 ") from MySQL table to hdfs. I expect the query to work given that the MySQL query alone is valid, yet I get a MySQL syntax error. Alternatively I could import using the upper and lower limits and then merge files later, which long and I don't want to do that.

Here is the query:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test \
--username=username \
--password=password \
--query 'select * from PURCHASE where purchase_id between 107 and 307 where $CONDITIONS' \
--target-dir /testpurchase \
--split-by purchase_id
```

Please, is there anything I am omitting here in the query, thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there were two ambiguous `WHERE clauses`, so changing last `WHERE $CONDITIONS` to `AND $CONDITIONS` did the trick.

```
  sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test \
--username=username \
--password=password \
--query 'select * from PURCHASE WHERE purchase_id between 107 and 307 AND $CONDITIONS' \
--target-dir /testpurchase \
--split-by purchase_id
```

And that a --boundary-query & --table could just do the work as well

```
  sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test \
--username=username \
--password=password \
--boundary-query 'Select 107,307 from purchase' \
--table purchase\
--target-dir /testpurchase \
```